The Theoretical and simulated S parameters of a TXline
If we consider a simple TXline of length \$l\$ and characteristic impedance \$Z_1\$, theoretically, its S parameters are
$$
S_{11}=\frac{Z_1-Z_0}{Z_1+Z_0}
$$
$$
S_{21}=e^{-j\theta}
$$
$$
S_{11}=S_{22}, S_{21}=S_{12}
$$
where \$\theta=\beta l\$ and \$Z_0\$ is the reference impedance. If we consider \$Z_0=Z_1\$ then \$S_{11}=S_{22}=0\$, which means that in dB \$S_{11,dB}=-\infty\$. But even if they are different, the S11 should be constant with frequency. If we simulate a generical TXline with a CAD (HFSS for example), the S11 is not constant and varies in frequency like in the photo. Why is that ? And in particular, why is it periodic ? I think I'm missing something here


$Z_0$ is always regarded as the characteristic impedance in my book. The generic t-line you simulated isn't enough of a description to explain the resulting graph so, please show a schematic and all values.

Your equation for S11 is for an infinite length line, not one with finite length.


But even if they are different, the S11 should be constant with frequency.

Yes. However, your dB S11 measurement is of the Z1 TX line terminated with Z0 at the far end. You therefore have a |S11| size reflection from each end. As the electrical length of the line changes with frequency, the phase of the far end reflection will swing round the whole circle, and add to the near end for a sum between 2*|S11| and 0.


If we consider a simple TXline of length \$l\$ and characteristic impedance \$Z_1\$, theoretically, its S parameters are
$$
S_{11}=\frac{Z_1-Z_0}{Z_1+Z_0}
$$

This is the equation for the reflection charateristi (\$S_{11}\$) of a fixed impedance load, or for the input of an infinite-length transmission line.
For a finite length line treated as a 2-port the formula is much more complicated. You can find it (along with the formulas for the other s-parameters) on the Wikipedia page "Transmission line".
As another answer says, the proper formula is dependent on the operating frequency, via the phase constant \$\beta\$ (closely related to \$\theta\$ in your equations).
